# query to Ignore the repeated column in leaderboard

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem my database looks like this [DATABASE STRUCTURE](http://prntscr.com/8kkup9)

i want to sort the lboard and ignore the repeated values

like this [REQUIRED OUTPUT](http://prntscr.com/8kkv1o)

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY to get single result for one user and MAX function to get its maximum score
the query will be like this

```
SELECT id, exam_id, user_id, MAX(lboard) FROM `leaderb` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY lboard DESC
```

Comment: not working properly bro 
i changes the lboard values like this [link](http://prntscr.com/8klg4y)
got output like this [link](http://prntscr.com/8klgga)

Comment: exam_id will not be constant it will changes from time to time

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, exam_id, user_id, MAX( lboard )
FROM  `wp_watu_takings` WHERE exam_id = 3
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY MAX( lboard ) DESC